# How do I automatically deleting rows and push the bottom cells up?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a printable template.
[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1viOZRVuzv63HV4oblcc2BmJbZvwGFZ9ZHoZqSwJi9mI/edit?usp=sharing) is the simple example.

So basically what I want is to automatically move up/down the blue cells in the "Invoice" sheet immediately below the red cells above without empty rows in between. For example, if the customer ID is changed from 2 to 1, there will be only two red filled rows and therefore the blue cells will move up by 2. Similarly, if the customer ID is changed from 1 to 2, two additional red rows will be added and the blue cells will be pushed down by 2.

Is there any way to automate this, preferably without Apps Script? I would if it helps but I struggled so much bc I don't have any programming background.

It takes me hours just to do simple things without any excel/sheets experience and any tips or pointing me to the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) to build the whole invoice in one go, like this:

```
={ 
  query( 
    Log!A2:D7, 
    "select B, C, D 
     where A = " & 'Invoice Trigger'!B1, 
    0 
  ); 
  "Previous Balance", "", 'Invoice Trigger'!F3; 
  "Charged", "", 'Invoice Trigger'!E3; 
  "Due", "", 'Invoice Trigger'!F3 + 'Invoice Trigger'!E3 
}
```

Clear all red and blue cells in the 'Invoice' sheet and put the formula in cell `A2`.

The formula expects to find the Previous Balance figure in cell `'Invoice Trigger'!F3`.

If cell fill colors are of importance, use a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rules like `=isdate($A2)` and `=istext($A2)` to paint the rows the way you want.

Comment: thank you. it's been great help